# проблема со сборкой Xamarin.Android приложения

Tags: android, xamarin

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В списке ошибок ничего нет, только предупреждения

Comment: включите diagnostic лог билдера через **tools -> options -> project and solutions -> build and run**

Comment: @asm спасибо большое
!

Comment: в чём была проблема. сообщите, пожалуйста. это может помочь другим